# How to trim/cut string in java by symbol?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm working on a project where my API returns url with id at the end of it and I want to extract it to be used in another function. Here's example url:

```
 String advertiserUrl = http://../../.../uuid/advertisers/4 <<< this is the ID i want to extract.
```

At the moment I'm using java's string function called substring() but this not the best approach as IDs could become 3 digit numbers and I would only get part of it. Heres my current approach:

```
String id = advertiserUrl.substring(advertiserUrl.length()-1,advertiserUrl.length());
System.out.println(id) //4
```

It works in this case but if id would be e.g "123" I would only get it as "3" after using substring, so my question is: is there a way to cut/trim string using dashes "/"? lets say theres 5 / in my current url so  the  string would get cut off after it detects fifth dash? Also any other sensible approach would be helpful too. Thanks.

P.s uuid in url may vary in length too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions for this.

Use `String#lastIndexOf` along with `substring` instead:

```
String advertiserUrl = "http://../../.../uuid/advertisers/4";// <<< this is the ID i want to extract.
// this implies your URLs always end with "/[some value of undefined length]". 
// Other formats might throw exception or yield unexpected results
System.out.println(advertiserUrl.substring(advertiserUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

**Output**

```
4
```

**Update**

To find the `uuid` value, you can use regular expressions:

```
String advertiserUrl = "http://111.111.11.111:1111/api/ppppp/2f5d1a31-878a-438b-a03b-e9f51076074a/adver‌​tisers/9";
//                           | preceded by "/"
//                           |     | any non-"/" character, reluctantly quantified
//                           |     |     | followed by "/advertisers"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=/)[^/]+?(?=/adver‌​tisers)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(advertiserUrl);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

`2f5d1a31-878a-438b-a03b-e9f51076074a`

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem

Comment: What about if I want to extract the uuid from that same url? How could I achieve this? @Mena

Comment: Hmm I don't fully understand this, and when I try to run this I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` 
full url looks like this:

 `http://111.111.11.111:1111/api/ppppp/2f5d1a31-878a-438b-a03b-e9f51076074a/advertisers/9
` @Mena

Comment: @Tomas There might be some empty space somewhere - it wasn't working for me either with the given URL, then I rewrote it identical and it worked. Try copying the pattern initialization again. Also make sure you use the `if` condition to check whether it matches, otherwise you'll have an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: I've added else statement and apparently pattern does not match my url ;/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had to rewrite this regex and working solution was this: `"[^/.]+(?=/advertisers)"`

Comment: @Tomas you're welcome. The look-behind group can be omitted as you say, but it seems to work fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can either split the string on slashes and take the last position of the array returned, or use the lastIndexOf("/") to get the index of the last slash and then substring the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `lastIndexOf()` method, which returns the index of the last occurrence of the specified character.

```
String id = advertiserUrl.substring(advertiserUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, advertiserUrl.length());
```